# flutter variant flavors using flutter_flavorizr - how to customize app icon (both android and IOS)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, icons, variant

I am trying to figure out how to use flutter_flavorizr to make different variant apps with the same code based.

Here are some documentations that I have been trying to refer:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_flavorizr#-readme-tab-
https://medium.com/@angeloavv/easily-build-flavors-in-flutter-android-and-ios-with-flutter-flavorizr-d48cbf956e4

So far, I cant find much information/example detailing on customizing the app icon for the different apps (essentially its needed for both Android and IOS).

My question is how can I use flutter_flavorizr to customize the appicons for the different variant apps ? Is that possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package flutter_launcher_icons to generate different icons for different flavors.
https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons#flavor-support

Create icons configs with names matching your flavors (replace  with the actual flavor name): `flutter_launcher_icons-<flavor>.yaml`

and then run command:
`flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main -f flutter_launcher_icons-${flavor_name}.yaml`

Comment: I did this, but it override my icons so that all flavor still gets the same icon, how do I create different icons for different flavor?

Answer (score 0):

@Vit Veres answer is correct, but for android icon, when you run `flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main -f <your config file name here>` it will override your main `res` folder.

So before running this command, make a copy of this folder, then run the command then, copy `res` folder into a `android\app\src\<flavor_name>` and restore the original res folder.

Comment: Could you please explain the second line in your above solution, which folder to copy? I'm not getting this second-line context. ```So before running this command, make a copy of this folder, then run the command then, copy res folder into a android\app\src\<flavor_name> and restore the original res folder.```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have different app icons for different variants. Use the configuration shown below,

```
flavors:
   dev:
     app:
       name: "App Dev"
     android:
       applicationId: "com.app.dev"
       icon: "assets/dev/android_icon.png"
     ios:
       bundleId: "com.app.dev"
       icon: "assets/dev/ios_icon.png"
   prod:
     app:
       name: "App Prod"
     android:
       applicationId: "com.app.prod"
       icon: "assets/prod/android_icon.png"
     ios:
       bundleId: "com.app.prod"
       icon: "assets/prod/ios_icon.png"
```

And then add the images in `assets/prod/` and `assets/dev/` folders.

> NOTE: The `assets` folder lives in the root of the project.

Now, run

```
dart run flutter_flavorizr
```

For Android's adaptive icons, you have to manually create it and replace the once flutter_flavorizr created.

Comment: This will just use only one icon for all different app. It won't be like the way use ic_launcher with different dimension. It will just be one dimension throughout.